# Is there a site where I can ask about differences between the educational system in US and Spain?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a question regarding differences between how mathematics is taught in the US versus Spain. This is a question regarding highschool mathematics, so I feel the Academia SE would not be appropriate. Since this is a question about education more than it is really about mathematics, I feel like the mathematics SE would not be an appropriate place either.

Is there a site on this network where I can post my question?

Edit: here is my specific question:

> I live in the US, and as such, I'm used to my high school math courses
>   being essentially organized by subject material: algebra -> geometry
>   -> trigonometry -> precalculus -> calculus. I was talking to a Spanish friend about her math courses, and she said that in Spain, they don't
>   have those divisions. She was confused that our math courses would be
>   split up by subject material and said that her's are all together. So
>   my question is, how are mathematical topics of education divided
>   between different classes in Spain, and are those divisions at all
>   equivalent to the way we divide them in the US?

Comment: As a note, while that progression in the US may be *common*, when I was in high school in Seattle, they had what they called "integrated math" which was a combination of algebra/trig/geometry with a little precal mixed in...

Comment: Your question could be US vs Canada too, as its like spain there as I see it. In high school its only named if enriched math or not.

Answer (score 2):

I've found a [question](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/2220/6053) on the Stack Exchange for [Mathematics Educators](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/) which deals with this topic. That question itself a very broad question by Stack Exchange standards; however, none of the answers mention Spain. Given that your question focuses on a smaller 'subset', I suppose it's safe to say that you can ask your question there.

A relevant quote from their [help center](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (emphasis mine):

> From questions about helping children to appreciate numbers to suggestions on the advisement of doctoral students conducting original research, *a broad spectrum of questions about mathematics education is admissible*.

So the site is not limited to 'practical' questions faced by mathematics educators, and you don't need to be one to ask a question like yours.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you have already identified two sites that deal with your subject matter.

However, you seem to be seeking a list of comparisons to be made, each of which is likely to elicit opinions from any potential answerers so I think such a question would be closed as **too broad** and/or **primarily opinion-based**, no matter the SE site that you ask it on.

If the chat rooms of those sites allow it, then that may be the place to ask it more generically.

Comment: thanks, my question actually is more specific than a list of differences i believe

Comment: So it is not what are the "differences between how mathematics is taught in the US versus Spain"?  Perhaps you should include the actual question that you want to ask in your question.

Comment: alright, i edited my post

Comment: I think it is still too broad because to compare the two sets of topics/divisions will require multiple questions to be answered.